# How can I keep the originalSpeed but also to be able to change for a new speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class EnemyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;              // or the speed of rotation.
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    public float speedRange = 4;

    private float originalSpeed;

    private void Start() { originalSpeed = speed; }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!randomSpeed)
        {
            speedRange = 0;
            speed = originalSpeed;
        }
        else speed = Random.Range(1, speedRange);
    }
}
```

The problem is in `Update` at this part:

```
if (!randomSpeed)
{
    speedRange = 0;
    speed = originalSpeed;
}
```

If for example when running the game the speed was 3 now when I set it to false the speed value will be 3 all the time I can't change it now. But I want to be able to change the speed value to any value. I want that it will get back to the originalSpeed if I set to false but also to be able to change for a new speed and then update the originalSpeed to the new one.

The way I did it now I locked the speed when it's false.

Comment: If you have to use comments to explain your variable, then you've given it a bad name. I have no idea what `randomSpeed` does. Is it true if we are using a random speed, or we should use a random speed, or we have already used a random speed? I could go on. Also, you should really only include the relavent poritions of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it will lock the speed as you assign the value of speed by originalSpeed every frame.

To solve it, you should not put things inside the Update(). Also, try to use 'get set' syntax for those protected public variable.

Lets say you want to assign a value to the 'speed' only one time, when you click the randomSpeed checkbox.

```
private float randomSpeed
public float RandomSpeed
{
    get {return randomSpeed;}
    set {
        randomSpeed = RandomSpeed;
        if (!randomSpeed){
            speed = originalSpeed;
        } else {
            speed = Random.Range(1, speedRange);
        }
    }
}
```